# Custom SHAPED Layout with clipping bounds

Tags: android, android-layout

Well yes, I couldn't find anything that could help me for real so far... from `StackOverflow` to `libraries` and other things...

I need a custom shaped `FrameLayout` that is clipping his child inside of it. The problem is that I want this `shape` to be really custom, for example `shirt / hat / etc..`

So, somehow I want to clip child of `FrameLayout` inside the shirt let's say. I found something related to `onDraw` method, but I didn't find a way of getting pathData of a `vector`. . .

Any clear idea about how I could sort this up ( if possible ) is welcomed !

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use clip path. Your code can look something like:

```
private void updatePath() {
    path = new Path();
    // Draw your special shape...
}

@Override
protected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    return super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I saw something similar, but my problem (as I said) it's related to the `path` itself... How do I get it from `vector` or any other way of creating it ? Practically this `path` has to be path of the shirt ?

Comment: Can you share an example of your input vector?

Comment: Actually I have an XML file containing it, so I was thinking at it's `pathData`

Comment: It is not so simple and I don't Google intended us to use it the way you want to. However, this article - https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/understanding-vectordrawable-pathdata-commands-in-android-d56a6054610e can help you transform any path data to a `Path` object. In theory you can write a parser that will transform pathData programmatically and automate this.

Comment: So in the end I should write my own parser of the `pathData` string..
I've read that article already. Okay well, thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Google did something similar in VectorDrawable (VPath & VClipPath), but it is done in C++ code and will be probably hard to transfer and use in Java.

Comment: I will probably use a rectangle shape after all, but will try to write something that can get at least close to what I want :) Thank you again