# Download custom shaped image

Tags: android, image-processing, bounds

So, two days ago I asked about custom views with clipped child [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49133566/custom-shaped-layout-with-clipping-bounds)

I ended up using a simple `rectangle` shape, with a `radius` so it can be a bit rounded, and clip it's child, so far so good . . I ran into this problem now when I am actually trying to download whatever is inside this rectangle, but of course the downloaded image is a rectangle, how could I download it, with those clipped bounds ?[image]

Here is how it looks, quite ok. The problem would be when I download what's inside area..of course the downloaded image doesn't have rounded corners (or whatever the shape I use for the big area) ..

**EDIT:** this is how it kinda looks [image]

**Edit2:** Something like in [this](https://medium.com/@Tarek360/crop-a-shape-from-an-android-bitmap-9690b7432774) article, but I don't know how to get that `path` !

Comment: you want to store non-rectangle images or what? I don't understand your question

Comment: So, just for a better vision of this : on the shirt There is a `FrameLayout` with that dotted line as a background (it's a drawable file with `<shape>` tag as root , so I can clip childs as you can see in the image). I want to download the image from this `FrameLayout` I will add another picture showing the problem.. I want the downloaded image to be exactly on those bounds...

Comment: Basically, I would like to crop the image before download it..@Piglet Or at least, I think this will do the trick

Comment: digital images are always rectangular. there are many good reasons for that. some image formats provide an alpha channel which you can use to make things transparent.

Comment: I understand that, please take a look at my last edit, that's what I actually want to do, just that i am not sure how to get the path of my rectangle(or other shape) from `drawable` file